# tkinter. что я тут не так делаю? подскажите

Tags: python, tkinter, radiobutton

при выборе "много" или "мало" не показывает результат расчета функции. только 1 и 100. что я тут не так делаю? подскажите.

```
import tkinter as tk
import math

nn1 = 1
nn2 = 100
def press_go():
    lenght = len(range(nn1,nn2+1))
    num = math.ceil(math.log2(lenght))
    num1.set(f"Количество попыток {num}")

def search():
    n1 = 1
    n2 = 100
    bin1 = choice_num.get()
    
    while n1 <= n2:
        centr = (n1+n2) // 2
        bin_text.set(f"Ваше число {centr} ?")
        
        if bin1 == 3:
            bin_text.set(f"Готово")
            break
        elif bin1 == 1:
            n2 = centr-1
        elif bin1 == 2:
            n1 = centr +1
    
win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Поиск числа. v1.0")
win.geometry(f"300x350+1000+100")
win["bg"] = "#CD853F"

num1 = tk.StringVar()
choice_num = tk.IntVar()
bin_text = tk.StringVar()

tk.Label(win, text="Загадай число от 1 до 100").pack()
tk.Button(win, text="Начинаем", command=press_go).pack()
tk.Label(win, bg="#CD853F", textvariable=num1).pack()

tk.Label(win, bg="#CD853F", textvariable=bin_text).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(win, text="Много", variable=choice_num, value=1, command=search).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(win, text="Мало", variable=choice_num, value=2, command=search).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(win, text="Угадал", variable=choice_num, value=3, command=search).pack()


win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Показывает, только очень быстро и ты не видишь, как меняются числа. Ошибка в том, что цикл  `while n1 <= n2:` пробегает сразу же весь при однократном нажатии на кнопку. Сделай, например, так

```
txt = ""
while n1 <= n2:
    centr = (n1+n2) // 2
    txt = txt + " " +  str(centr)
    bin_text.set(f"Ваше число {txt} ?")
```

и увидишь, что цикл-то работает и поиск производится.

Тебе нужно, чтобы на каждую кнопку был только один шаг.

Comment: почти. выдает список чисел. но тут смысл выдавать постоянно одну и если она больше или меньше загаданной, то искать дальше. по принципу бинарного поиска.